# termcal, is week number present?

Tags: calendar, tikz-calendar, termcal

I am a happy user of termcal that I use to produce my weekly schedule. I am just wondering if there is a way/package/customization to produce a weekly summary. 
Let's say that my calendar knows for C1 to C4, given this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}

\begin{document}

\begin{calendar}{8/31/2014}{5}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}

% Description of the Week.
\calday[Sun]{\classday} % Sunday
\skipday\skipday % Monday, Tuesday
\calday[Wed]{\classday} % Wednesday
\skipday\skipday % Thursday, Friday
\calday[Sat]{\classday}


\options{C1}{\classday\weeklytext{MYSTUFF1}}
\options{C2}{\classday\weeklytext{MYSTUFF2}}
\options{C3}{\classday\weeklytext{MYSTUFF3}}
\options{C4}{\classday\weeklytext{MYSTUFF4}}

\end{calendar}

\end{document}
```

I would like to produce a table like this one:

```
Week1 C1 MYSTUFF1
      C2 MYSTUFF2
Week2 C3 MYSTUFF3
      C4 MYSTUFF4
```

any suggestions? I might consider to using tikz-calendar, if there is a quick way to port termcal into it to achieve the same results.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: How is LaTeX supposed to know which item goes with each week? The input doesn't make sense of this. Can you post a complete minimal working example?